# How can i remove an image of a button using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
@IBAction func game(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "x.png"), for: UIControlState())
}

@IBAction func newGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    clearImage()
}

func clearImage() {...}
```

i want a "clearImage" function that can be used in the "newGame" button to remove the image from the "game" button.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried setting the image to `nil`?

Comment: In your code the line to set the image should read `sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "x.png"), for: .normal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the button as an IBOutlet and connect it to your view. Then in clearImage() just set the image to nil:

```
  button.setImage(nil, forState: .normal)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the controlState value start with a lower-case letter (i.e. `.normal`)? That's the new convention in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

for swift 4:

```
 button.setImage(nil, forState: [])
```

Edited

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K